# I cannot find template ADO.NET Entity Data Model in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ado.net, entity, datamodel

In VS2010, I cannot find the template ADO.NET Entity Data Model from the Data section.
I was doing:

1. create a silverlight(version 4th) project with a WebSite
2. right click the web project, Add -> New Item -> Data Section(actually, I tried every one)

But I cannot find it!! It's weird!

Then,

1. I tried to reset my VS template, it didn't work
2. Tried to re-install VS2010, and I got the "Successful" message. also I am sure that the ADO.NET Entity Framework has been installed appropriately.

So, is there anything else I can do? can I just install this template to VS?

Answer (score 0):

i believe you can add a ADO.NET Entity Data Model in a windows class library
and reference that library where it is required. but you cannot add the data model in a silverlight library.

Update: 
in that case, i presuming the website is atleast targeting version 3.5 of the framework

for vs2010, you can check that the required template is available at the locations below
'%programfiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Data\1033\AdoNetEntityDataModelCSharp.zip'
'%programfiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\VisualBasic\Data\1033\AdoNetEntityDataModelVB.zip'
'%programfiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\Web\CSharp\1033\AdoNetEntityDataModelCSharp_ASPNET.zip'
'%programfiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\Web\VisualBasic\1033\AdoNetEntityDataModelVB_ASPNET.zip'

(in a x64 environment use 'Program Files (x86)' for %programfiles%)

hope that helps.
-ryan

Comment: Ryan, Thanks for your quick response, but I wasn't trying to add a ADO.NET Entity Data Model to "Silverlight" library, I right-clicked the "Web Site" project, this should work, but no, I lost the elf!